# Would the proof change if connected subspace became connected subset?

Tags: general-topology

"Let A be  a  connected  subspace  of X.  If A⊂B⊂cl(A),  then B is also connected"

I did this proof a few times before, but I realized the first time I did it, I misread subspace as subset but the answer was the same. I was wondering if the wordings did change to "Let A be a connected subset" instead of subspace, are there any changes to these proofs? Because if a subset is connected, its induced subspace topology is also connected. Now I am curious about problems where if we changed the wording from subspace to subset, the proof has to change a lot. I can't think of any where that is the case.

Comment: It's the same thing: a subset is a connected subset if and only if it is connected with respect to the subspace topology.

Comment: There are no such cases, in short.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider a subset  $A$ of a topological space $X$, we always consider it to have the subspace topology it inherits from $X$ if we talk about its properties (like compact, connected etc.). This is often implicit and not always mentioned.

There is no difference between a connected subset, or a connected subspace etc. But it's good to be aware of the fact that it's common practice.

Comment: But sometimes people define connectedness and compactness as relative properties. In this case it shouldn't be missed that they really depend only on the subspace itself and not on the surrounding space.

Comment: @user87690 Yes, that's usally one of the first theorems. There *are* some legitimate relative properties (but these are not  purely topological properties as such). Connectedness and compactness and most elementary properties are "absolute" in that they only depend on the subspace topology.